# How to extract blog posts from Ghost and import in Github hosted jekyll?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, jekyll, ghost-blog

Jekyll website has given this instruction but it's not complete. I downloaded ghost.db from ghost blog and Installed http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/ghost/ and jekyll-import gem and it's all dependencies. and ran the given command in above link. It ran but it's giving error

[image]

Also I don't have any local installation of jekyll website. It's hosted on github.

I want to move my blog posts of ghost to github hosted jekyll.

My OS is OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Did you install all the correct gems?  I've never done an import personally, but it looks like its a missing gem error.

Comment: @JitendraVyas How did you get the `ghost.db` file? I mean, did you copy it from `content/data` or downloaded it using the export button?

Comment: @TamerShlash I download from my ghost installation at DigitalOcean

Comment: @JitendraVyas did you find it somewhere like `content/data` or just logged into your Ghost installation and hit the "export" button?

Comment: @TamerShlash I connect to my ghost directory via SSH and downloaded ghost.db to my systm. Export installation of ghost option doesn't give ghost.db it gives .json file

Comment: @JitendraVyas according to [this support page](http://support.ghost.org/how-to-upgrade/#backing-up), you should stop your Ghost installation before downloading the database file. Also, your Ghost database should be SQLite.

Comment: @TamerShlash yes I stopped ghost server before to download ghost.db

Comment: @JitendraVyas Use http://sqlitebrowser.org to inspect and verify that the `ghost.db` file is in valid format, and that it does contain `posts` table; that could provide more info about why the import script is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your command from the folder where ghost.db is in.

If your not lauching your command from the db folder, you can give an absolute path like

```
"dbfile"   => "/home/user/ghost.db"
```

Or the database name is not the good one. Maybe `ghost-dev.db` or `ghost-prod.db`.

Comment: And the bounty as gone. To bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to export your ghost blog to json and then convert that json file into markdown files for Jekyll GitHub pages.

The json file is pretty self explanatory, so you could write a simple program to parse the file and create markdown files from it.

The process would look like this:

- read the json file into memory.
- parse the posts from `db.data.posts`.
- for each post:

  - the markdown content is in the `post` `markdown` property.
  - create your front matter from the other `post` properties.
  - write a file with the front matter and original markdown, pre-pending the file name with the date into a `_posts` folder in your output folder.
  - note: if the `page` property is 0, it's a post, if it's 1 it's a page. If it's a page, the file should go in the root of your output folder without the date in the file name.

Each post file should look something like this:

```
---
layout: post
title: Welcome to Ghost
permalink: /welcome-to-ghost
date: 2017-04-25 20:54:20
published: false
tags: 
---

You're live! Nice. We've put together a little post to introduce you to the Ghost editor and get you started. You can manage your content by signing in to the admin area at `<your blog URL>/ghost/`. When you arrive, you can select this post from a list on the left and see a preview of it on the right. Click the little pencil icon at the top of the preview to edit this post and read the next section!
```

If you're looking for an existing utility, or sample code, try [GhostToGitHubPagesConverter](https://github.com/jrummell/GhostToGitHubPagesConverter). It's a dotnet core console app that will run on windows, mac or linux.

Full disclosure, this is my github project.